# docker login with domain name does not work from Mac in same LAN, but from other devices

Tags: macos, docker, nexus3

I can't log in to a self hosted docker registry from my Mac, other devices work.

Home LAN, all in 192.168.0.xxx:

- raspberry pi with docker version 20.10.8
- Mac with MacOS and docker version 20.10.8
- PC hosting the registry at 192.168.0.12: ubuntu with docker version 19.03.13

The reverse proxy setting is:

```
my.sub.domain.com {
    reverse_proxy /* 192.168.0.12:8082
}
```

The docker registry is supplied by `Nexus 3`. I've set up a `http` connector a port 8082.
My reverse proxy terminates ssl/https, internally http is used.

What I did

- raspberry pi:

  - docker login `my.sub.domain.com -u user -p pass`
  - result: `Login Succeeded`
- mac, option 1:

  - docker login `my.sub.domain.com -u user -p pass`
  - result: `Error response from daemon: Get "https://my.sub.domain.com/v2/": Service Unavailable`
- mac, option 2:

  - docker login 192.168.0.12:8082 -u user -p pass
  - result: `Login Succeeded` (I've added that IP to insecure registries)

`dig my.sub.domain.com` returns the same result for both `raspberry pi` and `mac`.

I do not want to specify the IP to log in, I want to specify the domain name.
Logging in also works via the internet from a different location.
What is happening with the Mac docker? How can I debug this further?

Comment: Is there any HTTP proxy configured?

Comment: None that I configured, I am at home. But I exchanged my traefik2 reverse proxy against caddy recently.